# Variance of a random discrete sequence

Tags: discrete-signals, random

If $x[n]$ is a discrete random sequence with uniform distribution having mean $\mu = 2$ and variance $\sigma^2 = 3$, if passed through a moving average filter to get an output of

$$\frac{x[n] + x[n-1] + x[n-2]}{3}$$

what would be the the variance of the new signal?

I am getting 2 answers like 1 and 3. Which is correct?

Comment: Your question cannot be answered without knowledge of the _autocorrelation function_ of the sequence. The variance of a sum is the sum of the variances only if the random variables comprising the sum are _uncorrelated_ or, more strongly, _independent._  The mean being $2$ or the distribution being uniform has very little to do with the matter.

Comment: @DilipSarwate : This is from an ISRO question paper.

Comment: @dexterdev: As Dilip pointed out, the question is unanswerable in its current state. I'm not sure what an "ISRO question paper" is.

Comment: I suppose ISRO is the Indian Space Research Organization, and this question is from some kind of examination administered to applicants or new hires. It is still, unfortunately, and regardless of what the ISRO people say, unanswerable in its present form. For _uncorrelated_ random variables (including as a special subcase _independent_ random variables), the answer is $1$.  The answer $3$ will be obtained only if _all_ the $x[n]$ equal the _same_ random variable $y$ with variance $3$ so that $(x[n] + x[n-1]+x[n-2])/3 = (y+y+y)/3 = y$ has variance $3$ for all choices of $n$.

Comment: Yes ISRO is Indian space Research organisation. Thank you for the effort.

Comment: I think the question suggest the samples are IID. Hence one could solve it. Pay attention the Mean isn't zero. OK, Dilip, I see you answered that. I think you should put it as an answer and the question will be marked as solved.